# How to save exec plugin output of the latest mercurial tag?

Tags: maven, mercurial

I am trying to get mercurial repository last version tag. This is what I have done so far:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>hginfo</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>hg</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>parent  </argument>
                    <argument>--template</argument>
                    <argument>'{latesttag}+{latestance}\n'</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I would like to save the output of that command (last hg tag) into file version.properties, but I would also like to have posibility to alter maven output repository into `target/prod-last-hg-tag/app.war` (so maybe also to have possibility to store it in variable which could be accesed later for altering maven output directory).
How can I do this? Is it possible to do this scenario with another maven plugin buildnumber-maven-plugin?
Please help. Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
mismas

Comment: You can configure [`outputFile`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html#outputFile) to redirect the output into a file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That helped, but also I was missing <phase>initialize</phase> right before goals tag. Now I get the latest tag which is UAT, but I also get some extra characters like 'UAT+'. Do you know how to remove those quotes and plus sign?

Comment: I figured it out, my bad. I only had to do:  <argument>{latesttag}</argument> instead of <argument>'{latesttag}+{latestance}\n'</argument> :)